# Add COUNT in DISTINCT query and two tables related query

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I wants to include COUNT in the below query, I have tried changed it but it doesn't work. The Javascript for selectedcount and average isn't working because of the missing COUNT in the query (I guess). Can someone assist me on this? Thank you.

**Dropdown selection**

```
<select id="prg" name="prg"  class="demoInputBox" style="padding: 3px; width: 350px;">
<option value="">Select Programme</option>

    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT student_prg FROM marketing_data, current_sem WHERE marketing_data.intake_year = current_sem.intake_year";
    $do = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['student_prg'].'" data-count="'.$row['count'].'">'.$row['student_prg'].'</option>';
                      }
                  ?>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var selectedprg = '';
      var selectedcount = '';
      var average = '';

      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The total number of students in the selected program " +selectedprg + " <br>is " +selectedcount + " , it is predicted that " +average+ " students in +city+ will enroll for the upcoming semester <br> based on the data of 3 semesters back.";
      }

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#prg").change( function(){
          selectedprg = $('#prg option:selected').text(); 
          selectedcount = $('#prg option:selected').data('count');
          average = selectedcount / 3 + 5;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Queries that I've tried:

```
"SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT student_prg) FROM marketing_data, current_sem WHERE marketing_data.intake_year = current_sem.intake_year";
```

Screencapture:
[image: Output]

The total number of students in the selected program Diploma in Computer Science (Industrial Computing)
is **+selectedcount**, it is predicted that **+average** students in +city+ will enroll for the upcoming semester
based on the data of 3 semesters back.

This **bold** variable the one couldn't read from the existing query.

**marketing_data table**
[image]

**current_sem table**
[image]

Comment: Hi Rajeshwari - Where are you calculating count and average number of students. In your select query, I can only see that you are pulling distinct program name from tables. Give us some sample data and desired output.

Comment: Hi VarunT - The count and average calculating in the Javascript. Before I added the DISTINCT and join the two different tables. The calculation was working fine. I will editted the questions and give some screenshot on the desire output

Comment: Hi VarunT - Question has been updated,

Comment: Can you show sample data from the tables . You would ideally need count(distinct student_ID) for students. Can't say much without looking at sample data

Comment: Done @VarunT ...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can't use distinct and count without a group by.

You can count results :

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT student_prg FROM marketing_data, current_sem WHERE marketing_data.intake_year = current_sem.intake_year";

    $do = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($do);
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['student_prg'].'" data-count="'.$count.'">'.$row['student_prg'].'</option>';
                      }
                  ?>
```

Comment: "SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT student_prg) FROM marketing_data, current_sem WHERE marketing_data.intake_year = current_sem.intake_year GROUP BY student_prg";     No output @ShadeBob

Comment: Check my code ... I added mysql_nums_rows and updated the data-count

Comment: It shows value but incorrect value. Is there any possibilities to add COUNT only in the query ?

Comment: Do you want a counter of all students or a counter of students of each student_prg ?

Comment: For second solution sql is : "SELECT DISTINCT student_prg, count(student_prg) as count FROM marketing_data, current_sem WHERE marketing_data.intake_year = current_sem.intake_year group by student_prg

Comment: Thank you so much @ShadeBob. This works perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: If I wants to add another column in the count, I tried as "SELECT DISTINCT student_prg, count(student_prg, student_city) as count FROM marketing_data, current_sem WHERE marketing_data.intake_year = current_sem.intake_year group by student_prg"; But it doesn't works, do I needs to do something in the option value?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT student_prg, count(student_prg) as countprg, count(student_city) as countcity FROM marketing_data, current_sem WHERE marketing_data.intake_year = current_sem.intake_year group by student_prg. You will now have $row['countcity'] and $row['countprg']